# a way to find the smallest +ve integer with exactly x factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, algorithms

If I am given a number, for example 6, what's the mathematical algorithm for finding the smallest positive integer with 6 factors. It will be 12, but I need a formula which can give me the answers for higher number of factors such as 18.

I'm confused with this. A clear explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to be more precise ;-) $1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 = 1$ is an integer with 6 positive integer factors. Do you want 6 distinct positive integer factors? 6 prime factors?

Comment: @parsiad I suppose "factor" means "divisor" here.

Comment: A way to find x distinct factors. For example 12 has 6 distinct factors - 1,2,3,4,6,and 12. So i want an algorithm/ method to find it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485372/how-to-determine-the-smallest-numbers-with-n-factors

Comment: I see, but why does that method work and how can it improved so that it works for all numbers including primes

Answer (score 1):

The number of positive divisors of $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ (where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and the $a_i$ positive integers) is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$. For the smallest $n$ with a given number of factors, we will have that $p_1,\ldots, p_k$ are the first $k$ primes without gap, wlog in ascending order, i.e., $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, $p_3=5$, etc. (because if there were a gap, replacing the largest used prime with the smaller, left-out prime would make $n$ smaller).
And then we have $a_1\ge a_2\ge\ldots \ge a_k$ (again, because otherwise swapping exponents would make $n$ smaller: $p^aq^b<p^bq^a$ if $p<q$ and $a>b$). The possible choices for the $a_i$ now come from the factorization of the desired number of divisors.

For $18$ divisors, the factorizations of $18$ into one or more non-increasing factors are
$$18=9\cdot 2 =6\cdot 3,$$
leading to the candidate numbers
$$ 2^{17},\quad 2^83^1,\quad 2^53^2.$$
Among these, 
$$ 2^53^2=288$$
is the smallest.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please expalin the first line with an example cause i cant understand it. i.e. The number of positive divisors of =1122⋯ (where the  are distinct primes and the  positive integers) is (1+1)(2+1)⋯(+1).

Comment: $180$ has 18 divisors